# Beautiful Soup: How to extract text from this structure:

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-mining

I would like to access the timestamp text inside `title = ""`

And get this string "`23.12.2019 13:05:24`"

```
[<div class="pull_right date details" title="23.12.2019 13:05:24">
 13:05
        </div>]
```

I already know to access the proper text inside this div. But it happens it's just the hour. The full timestamp is what I need.

I'm using this structure currently:

```
ltimestamp = []
for tag in divTag:
    tdTags = tag.find_all("div", {"class": "pull_right date details"})    
for tag in tdTags:
    ltimestamp.append(tag.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have this element 
`<div class="pull_right date details" title="23.12.2019 13:05:24">13:05</div>`

if you want to get the '13:05' => value inside  tag, you do this
`print(tdTags.text)`

to get the value ('23.12.2019 13:05:24') of an attribute ('title'), do this
`print(tdTags['title'])`

I'll come back with beautifulsoup link to this explanation. read it somewhere before

documentation url:
`https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes`